# Truncate Multiline Centered Text & Add Ellipses

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how to truncate multiline text (in my case, after three lines) & add an ellipsis when the text is centered.

Right now, I have some css that hides the overflow text, but I haven't figured out a way to add the ellipsis.

`Text-overflow: ellipsis;` doesn't work since this is multiline.

Another solution suggests hiding/displaying a div w/ "..." in the bottom right of the text div, but this doesn't work for centered text.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery plugins, for example [dotdotdot plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).
The usage is very simple:

```
$(".container").dotdotdot();
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJG4R/)**